# Unable to upload image to server using Android Volley

Tags: php, android, server, android-volley

I am trying to upload an image picked by the user to the server using Android Volley. I have read other answers to this questions, but they suggest using multipart requests, but I would like to use Volley instead.

I am trying to upload the image selected by the user for the profile picture. I am supplying userID to identify the user and the image in the form of String, image will be stored in specific directory depending upon the userID. Server will true if the operation succeed and false otherwise.

**Here is the function to upload the image**

```
private void uploadImage() {
        //Showing the progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Uploading...", "Please wait...", false, false);
        String UPLOAD_URL = "http://parque.890m.com/upload-user-img.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        Log.d("response", s);
                        loading.dismiss();

                        //Showing toast message of the response
                        if (s.equals("true")) {
                            Log.d("upload_success", "successful upload : " + s);
                        } else if (s.equals("false")) {
                            Log.d("upload_failure", "successful upload : " + s);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("connection_failure", "connection failed");
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();

                        //Showing toast
                        Log.d("upload_error", "" + volleyError.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //Converting Bitmap to String
                String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
                Log.d("image_string", "" + image);

                //Getting Image Name
                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(UserProfile.this);
                String name = preferences.getString("id", null);

                //Creating parameters
                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                //Adding parameters
                params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
                params.put(KEY_NAME, name);

                //returning parameters
                Log.d("params : ", "" + params.toString());
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Creating a Request Queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        //Adding request to the queue
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }*/
```

**I have written a function to convert image to string**

```
 public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        return encodeToString(imageBytes, DEFAULT);
    }
```

**And the Server side Code is**

```
<?php

    require_once 'inc/connection.inc.php';

    if(isset($_POST['user'])){
         $success = false;
         $image = $_POST['image'];
         $name = $_POST['user'];

         $path = "uploads/$name";

         $actualpath = "http://parque.890m.com/$path";

         $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `photo_url` = $actualpath WHERE `user_id`= $name";

         if(mysqli_query($connection,$query)){
         file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
         $success = true;
            }

         echo json_encode($success);
         mysqli_close($connection);
    }
```

Server is returning false on uploading image and the image is not uploaded.

Comment: once try out my library https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking#uploading-a-file-to-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using multipart request while using volley:

First of all create a file named: MultipartRequest as follows:

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String> {
private MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
private final File file;
private final HashMap<String, String> params;

public MultipartRequest(String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, File file, HashMap<String, String> params)
{
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

    mListener = listener;
    this.file = file;
    this.params = params;
    buildMultipartEntity();
    buildMultipartEntity2();

}



private void buildMultipartEntity()
{
    entity.addBinaryBody(KEY_IMAGE, file, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), file.getName());
    entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    entity.setLaxMode().setBoundary("xx").setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    try
    {
        for ( String key : params.keySet() ) {
            entity.addPart(key, new StringBody(params.get(key)));
        }
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
    }
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType()
{
    return entity.build().getContentType().getValue();
}
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();

    if (headers == null
            || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap())) {
        headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");

    return headers;
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try
    {
        entity.build().writeTo(bos);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
/**
 * copied from Android StringRequest class
 */
@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    String parsed;
    try {
        parsed = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        parsed = new String(response.data);
    }
    return Response.success(parsed, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}}
```

Also we are using multipart request as we need to upload a file(image) here. So take image as file to upload using this code. Now where you are making StringRequest just make Multipart Request as follows:

```
  public void uploadImage()
{
    try {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

           HashMap params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        MultipartRequest sr = new MultipartRequest( UPLOAD_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if ((pDialog != null) && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
                Log.d("file", f + "");
                Log.d("", ".......response====" + response.toString());

                ////////
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    String serverCode = object.getString("code");
                    if (serverCode.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                    }
                    if (serverCode.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        try {

                            if ("1".equals(serverCode)) {
                                JSONObject object1 = object.getJSONObject("data");

                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if ((pDialog != null) && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
                ;
                //  VolleyLog.d("", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Timeout Error",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    VolleyLog.d("", "" + error.getMessage() + "," + error.toString());
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    VolleyLog.d("", "" + error.getMessage() + "," + error.toString());
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    VolleyLog.d("", "" + error.getMessage() + "," + error.toString());
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    VolleyLog.d("", "" + error.getMessage() + "," + error.toString());

                }
            }

        }, f, params);
        sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(100000*2,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        sr.setShouldCache(true);
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(sr);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: MultipartEntity is depreciated in api 23. I already specified in the question that I don't want to implement Multipart requests.

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash but it still works with api 23, you can try. If you want to work with volley only, then this is the only way.

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash have you tried it? Well i am working with the same code and it is working perfectly. Actually for that you need to add two files also: httpmime, httpcore.

Comment: you can download the jars from  http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/httpmime/httpmime-4.3.jar.zip  and  http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/httpcore/httpcore.jar.zip.

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash put these files into a lib folder and set fileDependency.

Comment: what is buildMultipartEntity2() ? I am getting it as error. ContentType.create() is not being resolved too.

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash Sorry my mistake... i have that code in my project, so you can delete it. no issues.